# Embedding into $C\times [0,1]$

Tags: gn.general-topology

> Every totally disconnected separable metric space of dimension $n$ homeomorphically embeds into $C\times \mathbb R ^n$.

Is something like this known? $X$ is *totally disconnected* means that every point in $X$ is equal to the intersection of all clopen sets containing the point.  $C$ is the Cantor set.

It is known that there are totally disconnected spaces of arbitrary dimension. But what about just $n=1$?  How might we prove $X$ embeds into $C\times [0,1]$?

Comment: What definition of dimension are you using?

Comment: @AmirSagiv for example, dimension $1$ means there is a basis of open sets with zero-dimensional boundaries.

Comment: Thanks! So everything here is inside  $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Your notion of totally disconnected is non-standard. Normally this means that the components of $X$ are singletons. For you it's the quasicomponents that are singletons.

Comment: @AmirSagiv All the usual dimension functions coincide in separable metric spaces.

Comment: "One-to-one"? What if |X|=2?

Comment: So @AmirSagiv he seems to be using small inductive dimension $\operatorname{ind}(X)$.

Comment: Your definition of "totally disconnected" is usually called 'totally separated". Using another terminology might be confusing, since "totally disconnected" (= connected components are singletons) is usually weaker.

Comment: @YCor I have seen that terminology, but only rarely.  Most authors (including Engelking!) use "hereditarily disconnected" for singleton components, and "totally disconnected" for singleton quasi-components.

Comment: @D.S.Lipham I can believe that a few authors used this... but "most authors"..., I'll check when I'm in a library...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question is negative even in dimension $n=1$.

A suitable counterexample can be constructed as follows.

By a [result of Dranishnikov](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1987v057n01ABEH003059), there exists a self-map $f:M_1\to M_1$ of the Menger cube $M_1$ such that for any $y\in M_1$ the preimage $f^{-1}(y)$ is homeomorphic to $M_1$. Now take any topological copy $Y\subset M_1$ of $[0,1]$ and consider the preimage $X:=f^{-1}(Y)$. Fix a countable dense subset $Q\subset Y$ and repeating the construction of the Bernstein set, construct a subset $B\subset f^{-1}(Y\setminus Q)$ such that $f{\restriction}B$ is injective and $B$ intersects each compact set $K\subset X$ that has uncountable image $f(K)$. The zero-dimensionality of $Y\setminus Q$ and the injectivity of the map $f{\restriction}B:B\to Y\setminus Q$ implies that the space $B$ is totally disconnected.

We claim that $B$ cannot be embedded into the product $C\times[0,1]$ of the Cantor set and the interval. Assuming that there exists an embedding $h:B\to C\times[0,1]$, we can use the Lavrentiev Theorem to extend $e$ to a topological embedding $\bar h:G\to C\times[0,1]$ of some $G_\delta$-set $G\subset f^{-1}(Y\setminus Q)$ of $X$. The construction fo $B$ ensures that the projection $f(X\setminus G)$ is countable. So, we can find a point $y\in Y\setminus f(X\setminus G)$. For this point the preimage $f^{-1}(y)$  is contained in $G$ and hence admits an embedding into $C\times[0,1]$, which is not possible as $f^{-1}(y)$ is homeomorphic to $M_1$ (which does not embed into $[0,1]$).

---

**Remark 1.** The constructed example is essentially non-Borel. It would be interesting to know what happens for totally disconnected Polish spaces of dimension 1. Do they embed into the product $C\times[0,1]$?

**Remark 2.** A topological space $X$ is called *almost zero-dimensional* if it has a base of the topology consiting of open sets $U$ whose closures $\bar U$ are intersections of open-and-closed sets. By a result of [Dijsktra and van Mill](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-08/S0002-9939-07-08971-X/S0002-9939-07-08971-X.pdf) each almost zero-dimensional space embeds into the complete Erdos space and the latter space embeds into $C\times[0,1]$.